# Remove replication from an MS Access Database?

Tags: database, ms-access, database-replication

I have a Microsoft Access database (*.mdb), that we'll call `Admin.mdb` that is linked to from several other `*.mdb's` that users use on their machines.

We're upgrading to the latest version of MS-Access 365, (Microsoft Office Professional Pro 365) and it does not support replication;

When I run the databases in Access 365 that link to it, I get an error message that reads:

> "The current version of Microsoft Access does not support replicated
>   databases.  To use this database, open in a previous version of
>   Microsoft Access"

The `Admin.mdb` database at some point supported replication, but the servers that it replicated to (the design master) are long gone at this point.

In an attempt to remove replication from `Admin.mdb` I ran the [following script](http://www.extramiledata.com/remove-replication-from-a-ms-access-database/) on it from a blank `.mdb` file.  The script attempts to remove the replication by copying / recreating everything from `Admin.mdb` to an empty `db1.mdb` file.

It works to a point, however some of the files end up with an error message like this...

```
3259 Invalid field data type.
```

...when recreating the tables.

I've run the script using MS-Access 2003 and MS-Accesss 2007 and I still end up with the same errors.

I tried skipping the tables by adding them to the if statement for skipping system tables with a `<>`, but it just misses alot of the tables.

My hunch is that the `Admin.mdb` file itself is very old.  Maybe it was created in MS-Access 2000 or something like that.

Is there a kb out there that specifies what data types have been deprecated?

It appears to be occurring on fields with a `Number` (type `20`) field.

Looks like the issue might be that we're using [DAO to do this](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/create-new-field-type-dbdecimal.1644919/) when what we need to use is ADOX...

Answer (score 1):

I think when the database was set up to support replication one or more fields to track the changes were added to the tables. These will probably be your DAO fields of type Decimal (const = 20).

I would suggest that you remove these fields (since you won't be needing them anymore) and try importing the objects into a new database again.

Comment: Actually I think you can just import the tables from the replicated *.mdb into another empty database using the GUI...or do I lose something important in the process?

Comment: I thought it was these fields that were causing the problem? I would suggest that you remove them since they were created to track the replication and you're not going to be replicating the database anymore. Unless you're using them for anything else I think they're redundant.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need replication, then create new database with .accdb and import all the tables using old version of access. Now you should be able to open this in new version.